# Kakfa: Message ordering

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to process and publish messages with the same key in sequential order. For example, if there are three messages for "key1" (1, 2, 3) and another three for "key2" (4, 5, 6), the desired outcome should be either [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] or [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]. I understand that Kafka assigns messages with the same key to the same partitions, and having a separate consumer for each partition can solve this problem.

However, I'm concerned about what happens if a consumer fails and both topics are reassigned to the same consumer. How can I ensure ordering in Kafka despite this potential issue? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.